# Where to place auth.php in Lumen Framework?

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, lumen

I'm currently following this tutorial:
https://computerhalbwissen.de/jwt-auth-wie-man-eine-rest-api-mit-dem-lumen-framework-um-eine-jwt-authentifizierung-erweitert/

Yeah, I know its german. But that doesn't matter much, since you don't need to read it through to help me.
I'm at the point where I need to place this code into an auth.php file:

```
return[
  'defaults' => [
    'guard' => env("AUTH_GUARD", "api"),
    'passwords' => 'users',
  ],
  'guards' => [
      'api' => [
          'driver' => 'jwt',
          'provider' => 'users',
      ],
  ],
  'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
  ],
  'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
  ],
]
```

The problem is that Lumen doesn't have this file by default. I can copy it from `vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/config` though.
The only problem is:
I don't know where to place this file in my lumen project xD

Can someone please give me a lift?
I do find several questions on the internet on WHERE this auth.php inside a lumen project can be found, and they are all answered with the info I've shown you above. But none of these sources tells me where I need to place my copy of auth.php inside the lumen framework xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it inside `app/config/` folder

why there?

Because of Laravel framework... if there is something missing in Lumen and you need it, try to look where is that in Laravel and act accordingly. ;)